# How do I turn off try/catch block code completion in ReSharper?

Tags: autocomplete, resharper, code-completion

When I start typing a try/catch block, ReSharper causes it to be expanded from

```
try {
```

to

```
try
{
}
catch(Exception)
{
}
```

I appreciate ReSharper trying to do me a favour, but this is one of those instances where I'd prefer to do it myself seeing as I'm often going back and adding the `try` block later, or typing a `try`/`finally` block without a `catch` clause.

Where do I turn off this behaviour in ReSharper?

Comment: Nathan, for try finally you can add type tryf. However, I'm curious as to why this would cause a problem for you.

Comment: @Hadi because I usually type a code block and then go back and add the try/catch/finally bits afterwards, which means I don't want the code completion pasting in the extra bits where I'm typing because that's not where I want it.

Comment: In that case consider using the try..catch and try..finally Surround Templates.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

ReSharper menu / Live Templates

Under Predefined Templates / C# / Imported Visual C# Snippets

Uncheck try and tryf.

Comment: In Resharper 8.1, the option is under ReSharper menu -> Templates Explorer... -> Scopes -> C#.

Comment: For 2017.2.1 it's ReSharper menu -> Tools -> Templates Explorer ->Scopes -> C#